# Want to create a python function from a data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that has various columns, one of them being `sex` which has 3 different value types:

- male
- female
- NaN

and the other is `employment` types:

- employed
- unemployed

How do I create a function that takes in two strings (representing the the column names of interest) e.g function(`sex`, `employment`) and say I want to assign values in the data frame whose `sex` column value is Male = 1, Female = 2, NaN/other = 5 f and for `employment`, employed = 10, unemployed = 5 - Then make the function return the total of the two values above?

e.g function('Male', 'employed')

```
output = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be hundreds of ways to do this and I am still learning. So

1. Create a dictionary for mapping

`d = {'male': 1, 'female': 2, nan: 5, 'employed': 10, 'unemployed': 5}`

2. Create new columns with map integer values

`df['Sex_Value'] = df['Sex'].map(d)`

`df['Employement_Value'] = df['Employement'].map(d)`

`df['Total'] = df['Sex_Value'] + df['Employement_Value']`

3. there are multiple ways here too

`df.query("Sex == 'male' & Employement == 'employed'")['Total']`